# TypeScript Compiler: how to get FunctionDeclaration of the original function from CallExpression?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm just starting to hack on TypeScript internals and I'm puzzled with how do I get `Signature` or `FunctionDeclaration` of the original function given a reference to its usage in an arbitrary `CallExpression`.

Consider the example:

```
class A<T> {
    ...
}

function f<T>(): A<T> {
    return new A<T>();
}

function test(): void {
    const foo = f;
    foo<number>();
}
```

Given a reference to `foo<number>()` CallExpression I can easily infer its materialized type as well as the type of its return value with `typechecker.getTypeAtLocation(node)`. However, what I'd actually like to do is to get the type of the original function, which is `function f<T>(): A<T> { ... }`, and I'm not sure how do I achieve that.

I would appreciate any help with that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the symbol of the type and then you can get the declarations for the symbol:

```
import * as ts from 'typescript'

let p = ts.createProgram({
    rootNames: ["test.ts"],
    options: {

    }
})

const t = p.getTypeChecker();

var source = p.getSourceFile("test.ts");

const decl = source.statements[2] as ts.FunctionDeclaration; // function test(): void {....}
const fnCallStatement = decl.body.statements[1] as ts.ExpressionStatement; // foo<number>();
const fnCall = fnCallStatement.expression as ts.CallExpression; // foo<number>()
const fnTarget = fnCall.expression; // foo 
let type = t.getTypeAtLocation(fnTarget) // <T>() => A<T>
let symbol = type.getSymbol() // symbol: f
let fnDecl = symbol.getDeclarations()[0]
console.log(fnDecl.getFullText());
// output: 
// function f<T>(): A<T> {
//     return new A<T>();
// }
```

Comment: If there are overloads of the declaration, how do you determine which one is being used? For example, if `symbol.getDeclarations()` returns a four element array, then `symbol.getDeclarations()[0]` might not give you the relevant declaration.

Comment: Found the answer: if overloads are a concern, then you want `t.getResolvedSignature(fnCall)` rather than `symbol.getDeclarations()[0]`.